# Как можно реализовать автоматическое очищение (обновление) КЕШа?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Может правильно , а может не правильно сформулировал вопрос.

Суть в следующем: при добавлении, изменении или замене файлов на хостинге , сайт не видит этого пока не прожать ctrl + f5 , на мобилке также. Т.е. взять сафари. Нужно идти в настройки, очищать website data чтобы увидеть изменения на сайте.

Как можно реализовать автоматическое очищение КЕШа , чтобы не было данных процедур ?

Comment: просто добавляйте "версию" в местах подключения скриптов, например так : `<script src=".../script.js?v_1.1"></script>`

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych при этом сохраняя также файлы на диске с версией?

Comment: @AntonBrock нет, файли сохраняйте без версий. ето же просто GET запрос, а версией добавляеться просто гут параметр и браузер думает что запрос другой и перезакачивает файл

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych я не понимаю